# ERROR: http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing: UNTRUSTED signature

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, alpine-linux

I am new to this, but I enherited a project, where runtime build is created with dockerfile and commands like this:

```
# Build runtime image

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine

RUN echo "http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories;

RUN apk update && apk add libgdiplus

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
```

The gitlab pipeline shows this:

```
Step 15/20 : RUN apk update && apk add libgdiplus

96 ---> Running in 95f8ebccb602

97fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

98fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

99fetch http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz

100ERROR: http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing: UNTRUSTED signature

101WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.24c95890.tar.gz: No such file or directory

102v3.10.9-43-g3feb769ea3 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main]

103v3.10.6-10-ged79a86de3 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community]

1041 errors; 10355 distinct packages available

105Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update && apk add libgdiplus' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I know that the keys have been rotated and I have to upgrade alpine somehow, but adding `RUN upgrade`, or `RUN apk add -X https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main -u alpine-keys` doesn't change anything. Can someone please tell me what do I need to do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we have come across this problem and it is because alpine linux edge signing keys rotated ([link](https://www.alpinelinux.org/posts/Alpine-edge-signing-keys-rotated.html), according to this official announcement). You have to execute this command inside the `Dockerfile`.

```
apk add -X https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main -u alpine-keys
```

Another way is to upgrade the base image, in your case the `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-alpine`, to a newer version.

Comment: When I add the ```apk add -X https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main -u alpine-keys``` command I simply get another error, this time like this:
```ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main: UNTRUSTED signature```

Comment: Then try to update the base image of alpine, it was the second option

Answer (score 8):

**SOLVED** - You need to add **--allow-untrusted**

```
RUN apk add -X https://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main -u alpine-keys --allow-untrusted

RUN echo "@edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update
```

Comment: You should know what you are doing, if current network is untrusted, this might lead to traffic hijacking. Don't do that unless you were asked to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Just add  ***--allow-untrusted*** at the end and you are done

Refer this link: https://github.com/rayluo/grin/blob/master/Dockerfile.alpine

```
RUN apk add wqy-zenhei --update-cache --repository http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing --allow-untrusted
```